# ¿Por qué antiguamente se consideraba a la letra X una semivocal? ¿Qué era una semivocal entonces?

Tags: significado, pronunciación, historia, letras

Hoy día la se considera a la letra **[X](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c6rWX57)** como la "vigésimoquinta letra del alfabeto español". Pero no siempre ha tenido esa definición. Por ejemplo, en 1884 era la "vigésima sexta letra del abecedario castellano y vigésima primera de sus consonantes". Y en 1852 era la "vigésima quinta letra de nuestro alfabeto y decimanona de las consonantes" (vamos cambiando los órdenes). Pero en esta versión, y ya en todas las anteriores hasta Covarrubias en 1611, se añadía:

> Es una de las semivocales.

Hoy día se conoce una [semivocal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XYiTATS) como:

> *Fon.* Tradicionalmente, dicho de un sonido vocálico: Que aparece tras la vocal silábica en los diptongos y triptongos; p. ej., la /i/ en aire.

Este concepto de *semivocal* no parece encajar con el hecho de que la X fuera considerada una letra semivocal. ¿Por qué hasta 1852 se consideró a la letra X una semivocal? ¿Difería el concepto de *semivocal* por aquel entonces del que tenemos ahora?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En el [Diccionario de la Lengua Castellana, edición de 1783](https://books.google.es/books?id=4TxpAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=es#v=onepage&q&f=false), se usa "semivocal" para hablar, por lo que leo, de [cualquier consonante cuyo nombre empiece por vocal](https://books.google.es/books?id=4TxpAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA474&lpg=PA474&dq=covarrubias%20semivocal&source=bl&ots=QLSnxJxnat&sig=U7EcFZ3iID641s3ebURrhrGXrSY&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8vaC3iojUAhUHtxQKHRd1CsAQ6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=semivocal&f=false): la R (**e**re), la F (**e**fe), la L (**e**le)...

> **F**: Es letra semivocal por razón de sonar la *e* al principio y al fin; aunque Covarrúbias la pone entre las mudas.
>
> **L**: Es letra semivocal, porque su pronunciación empieza por vocal.
>
> **R**: Es letra semivocal, porque su pronunciación empieza y acaba en vocal.

Lo mismo aplicaría entonces para la X (**e**quis), aunque no sean tan explícitos:

> **X**: Es semivocal, y tomada de los latinos, entre los quales tenia el valor de dos consonantes; y unas veces fuerza de *c* y *s*, y otras de *g* y *s*.

Además, como buen diccionario, contiene la definición de "semivocal":

> [SEMIVOCAL](https://books.google.es/books?id=4TxpAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA474&ots=QLSnxJxnat&dq=covarrubias%20semivocal&hl=es&pg=PA847#v=onepage&q&f=false) adj. que se aplica á la letra, que su pronunciación empieza con vocal, y aunque no constituya sílaba con otra consonante, tiene por sí un muy claro sonido. Las letras semivocales son seis F. L. M. N. R. S. *Semivocalis*

No incluyen la equis, a pesar de lo anterior. Pero la regla de empezar por vocal, sí que aplica. Será una errata ^_^

PD: Curioso que por aquel entonces se usase el punto y seguido para las enumeraciones.

Comment: No conseguía que me entrara en la cabeza como la pronunciación de una consonante podía empezar por vocal, hasta que has aclarado que no se refiere a la pronunciación del sonido sino del nombre de la misma. Ahora ya entiendo el concepto, ¡gracias! Y lo de usar el punto y seguido para las enumeraciones daría para otra pregunta sobre historia de la gramática.